# Replacing values in scipy sparse csr matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to replace -1 values by zeros in a `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` like this:

```
a = [ -1 0 -1 0 -1 1
      1 -1 0 -1 0 0 ]
```

Desired output:

```
b = [ 0 0 0 0 0 1
      1 0 0 0 0 0 ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach (linear-time operations on #nnz only):

```
from scipy.sparse import find, csr_matrix
import numpy as np

# Create the data (Taken from DavidG's answer! Thanks!)
data = np.array([-1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0, -1, 0, 0]).reshape(2, 6)
a = csr_matrix((data), dtype=np.int8)

nnz_inds = a.nonzero()
keep = np.where(a.data == 1)[0]
n_keep = len(keep)
b = csr_matrix((np.ones(n_keep), (nnz_inds[0][keep], nnz_inds[1][keep])), shape=a.shape)

# CHECK
print('a')
print(a.todense())
print('b')
print(b.todense())
```

Output:

```
a
[[-1  0 -1  0 -1  1]
 [ 1 -1  0 -1  0  0]]
b
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

The basic idea is simple:

- look up all positions where nonzeroes are (exploiting sparsity)
- filter above to get all positions where 1's are
- create a new matrix from scratch using the prepared positions & data (exploiting sparsity)